# XSD tool omit length on the field

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, wsdl

I'm using XSD tool to generate C# classes from a XSD schema. Why XSD.exe ommits length and other restrictions on data type? Can I manual enforce resctrictions (for example length) via attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no because the CLR type system does not support these features as easily as the XSD type system. To the best of my knowledge it is also not possieble to restrict the size of collections through an attribute.

The problem with size limitations on collections is when to apply them. If you create a new collection that should contain at least two elements, what should these elements be? The answer here is that XSD has a different purpose, namely validation, while the generated code mainly serves representation.

So if you want to validate your data, use the XSD with some XML Schmea processor for validation and then use the XSD generated classes to represent the data in memory for easy processing with C#.